# Read the two columns from a file and write a value in the third column

Tags: bash, shell, file

I have a text file with the following details.

```
#test.txt

team_id   team_level  team_state
23            2         
21            4
45            5
```

I want to be able to read the `team_id` column and `team_level` column contents.
Then I want to add the value of 45 to the `team_state` column after reading the respective team_id column entry and team_level column entry.

The flow would be like this: 
Read 23 and 2, then add 45 in the `team_state` column. 
Read 21 and 4, then add 45 in the `team_state` column. and etc.

With my current code, I am only able to read the column entries and I am not sure on how to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

```
# My code as of now
while read tm_id tm_level tm_state; do
    printf 'team_id: %s, and team_level: %s\n' "$tm_id" "$tm_level"
done < Project_Details.txt
```

```
#My final test.txt should look like this
team_id   team_level  team_state
23            2         45  
21            4         45
45            5         45
```

Comment: So no matter what are values of `team_id` or `team_level` you want to have `45` in 3rd column?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, the values in the 3rd column are fixed and I just want to fill it with 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this simple `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t\t' 'NF==2{$0 = $0 OFS "45"} 1' test.txt
```

```
team_id   team_level  team_state
23            2         45
21            4         45
45            5         45
```

Comment: Could you help me with a solution similar to the one I have used, as I want to be able to access the values and store then like in an array for later use? Can you refer to my code in the question?

Comment: @Anna: Please post a new question with this specific new problem.

Comment: `awk` is right tool to process tabular (row, column based) data. I don't want to suggest you a wrong tool. `awk` is full fledged language that can pretty much do everything you are trying to accomplish in `shell`.

Comment: I dont understand what this line of code does, ```'NF==2{$0 = $0 OFS "45"} 1'```. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: It checks if there are 2 fields in a given row `NF==2` and if it does then it adds output field separator and `"45"` to current row `$0`

Comment: How do I store these two fields, like in an array?

Comment: You have individual fields available as `$1`, `$2`, `$3`. Please read some good tutorial on `awk`.